# jhipster and current date to display and check

Tags: angular, typescript, jhipster

Seems crazy but I cannot find a way to compare in an html created by jhipster test if a date field is greater than current date.

I try to display the date read from DB and see 2020-12-12 then I try to display the current date. Searching in the net I find it's possibile to get the current date doing: `new Date()`. So I try to display this but runnig the page an error is displayed:

```
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Template parse errors:
Parser Error: Unexpected token 'Date' at column 5 in [ {{new Date()}} ] in...
```

how can I get the current date (for checking with the one read from db)?

Here the code of the myclass.component.html where I need to check the date:

```html
<div>
    <jhi-alert-error></jhi-alert-error>
...
    <div class="table-responsive" *ngIf="myclasses?.length > 0">
        <table class="table table-striped" aria-describedby="page-heading">
            <thead>
            <tr jhiSort [(predicate)]="predicate" [(ascending)]="reverse" [callback]="transition.bind(this)">
            <th...
            </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            <tr *ngFor="let myclasse of myclasses ;trackBy: trackId">
                <td>{{myclass?.id}}</td>
                ...
                <td>
                  {{ new Date() }}
                </td>
 ...
```

Comment: Can you share a bit more code so we see what's going on?

Comment: shure. I omit the jhipster structure, it's the standard jhipster one. So I have myclass.component.html myclass.component.ts and so on.

Comment: something to put in the ts file ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usually, it's much easier to work with dates using the [MomentJS](https://momentjs.com/) library since it is already integrated into JHipster.

If you want to know if a date is in the future, you can define a function in your `[entity].component.ts` that returns a boolean, like this:

```js
import * as moment from 'moment';
import { Moment } from 'moment';
...
  isFutureDate(date: Moment): boolean {
    return moment().isBefore(date);
  }
```

Then in your `[entity].component.html` you can call it like this:

```html
<td>
  Date is in the future: {{ isFutureDate(myclass.date) }}
</td>
```

Where `myclass.date` is the date you want to check.

If what you need is just to know the difference between that date and now, you can do that too very easily. In your `...component.ts`:

```js
import * as moment from 'moment';
import { Moment } from 'moment';
...
  getDateDiff(date: Moment): number {
    const diff      = date.diff(moment());
    const duration  = moment.duration(diff);
    return duration.asHours();
  }
```

And in your `...component.html`:

```html
<td>
  Difference in hours: {{ getDateDiff(myclass.date) | number: '2.0-0' }} hours
</td>
```

In this case `getDateDiff()` will return the difference in hours between the date you pass as argument (`myclass.date`) and the current date (`moment()`). It will be a negative number if the date to check is in the past.

MomentJS is a very powerful library you can check the full documentation [here](https://momentjs.com/docs/). Also, if you want, the documentation relative to the methods I used:

- [isBefore()](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/query/is-before/): Whether a date is before another
- [diff()](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/difference/): Difference between two dates in milliseconds
- [duration()](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/durations/): Wrapper to work with time durations easily
- [asHours()](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/durations/hours/): Get the amount of hours in a duration

Comment: Great, it works. I hope some usefull library could be built allready present (standard) in environment, so I could write moment().isBefore(mydate) for example.